# MySQL Workbench Error Code: 3819 when adding check constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

**Attributes**

[image]

I am trying to add a constraint check for an attribute. But I am getting errors. I have tried in upper and lower case. The name is correct as you can see from the image.  What is going wrong here?

```
ALTER TABLE supplier ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_supplier_size CHECK (supplier_size>= 15);
```

> 0 6   09:35:38    ALTER TABLE supplier ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_supplier_size
> CHECK (supplier_size>= 15)    Error Code: 3819. Check constraint
> 'CHK_supplier_size' is violated.  0.735 sec

Comment: Some of your existing data violate the constraint. Check and correct the data in the table first.

Comment: @Serg The biggest data in there is "Medium" which is 6 characters long.  I tried saying < 15 but get the same error.

ALTER TABLE supplier ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_supplier_size CHECK (supplier_size < 15);

Comment: Check data in the `supplier_size` column. Looks like it contains both supplier_size>15 and supplier_size<=15, or it contains NULL.

Comment: @Serg  I don't know how to add more images to my post so I added it to imgur.  You can see the existing table.  There isn't anything more.

https://imgur.com/a/cb2YIgW

Comment: You are comparing varchar data to int value. Definetly it fails. Do you mean  `CHAR_LENGTH(supplier_size) < 15` ?

Comment: @Serg  No, I am trying to use the  CHECK constraint.

Comment: I believe Serg realizes that aspect, his suggestion is to be used _with_ the check constraint as the condition: `... CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(supplier_size) < 15)`

Comment: @PaulT. Thank you! That worked!  I didn't understand what serg said.